# What does a single ampersand ('&') operator do in PHP?

Tags: php, operator-keyword

```
$array1 = array("a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3, "d"=>4, "e"=>5);
print_r(array_filter($array1, "odd"));


function odd($var)
{
    // returns whether the input integer is odd//

    return($var & 1);
}
```

In the return value what do `&` operator ?? how it return odd number

Comment: RTFM: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Comment: The usage of `&` here has nothing to do with arrays .. consider if there was no array and odd was called as `odd(13)` and `odd(42)`.

Comment: goto https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php
-> User Contributed Notes -> searchBy("nicolaj")->read()

Answer (score 11):

It is bitwise operator AND.

For example,  `($a & $b)` evaluates both `$a` and `$b` is turned "on" (i.e. equal to 1)

See this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Comment: Add an explanation? He asked what it does, not just what it is.

Comment: Or just close this one

Comment: Closed anyway @ArmelLarcier

Comment: Marked as close & added explanation :)

Comment: & is bitwise operators which convert operands to bit-level and then perform operation. let me give an example. here are two operands

5 ( 0101 in bit level ) and 1 ( 0001 in bit level ). AND(&) operation of both the numbers will give  o/p of  0001, and that will be same for all the odd numbers. so result will be turned on for all odd numbers.

Comment: @BhargavKaklotara Great